# Feynman diagram - shorten legs in tikz-package

Tags: tikz-feynman

How do I shorten the external legs and make the blob bigger in the following code using the tikz-feynman package?

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{feynman}
        \vertex[blob] (m) at ( 0, 0) {\contour{white}{}};
        \vertex (a) at (-2,-2);
        \vertex (b) at ( 2,-2);
        \vertex (c) at (-2, 2);
        \vertex (d) at ( 2, 2);
        \diagram* {
            (a) -- [photon] (m) -- [photon] (c),
            (b) -- [photon] (m) -- [photon] (d),
        };
    \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are specifying the location of vertices manually, so you just need to adjust the coordinates of the vertices to shrink the lines.  Alternatively, you can use `node distance` to change the default separation between nodes if you are using the automatic placement:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\usepackage[compat=1.1.0]{tikz-feynman}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \def\leglength{1}
  \begin{feynman}
    \vertex[blob] (m) at (0, 0) {};
    \vertex (a) at (-\leglength,-\leglength);
    \vertex (b) at ( \leglength,-\leglength);
    \vertex (c) at (-\leglength, \leglength);
    \vertex (d) at ( \leglength, \leglength);
    \diagram* {
      (a) -- [photon] (m) -- [photon] (c),
      (b) -- [photon] (m) -- [photon] (d),
    };
  \end{feynman}
\end{tikzpicture}

\feynmandiagram [horizontal=a to b, node distance=1.5cm] {
  a -- [photon] o [blob] -- [photon] b,
  c -- [photon] o        -- [photon] d,
};
\end{document}
```

[image: output 1]

[image: output 2]